# Get bundle seed ID through codesign utility

Tags: iphone, ios, applescript

How can I get the Bundle Seed ID through codesign utility.

I am able to get the Bundle ID through display option i.e.

```
codesign -dvvv <appPath>
```

I want the Bundle seed Id using codesign or any other way probably applescript.

TIA